# How to add another column to a bash script output?

Tags: bash, pipe

in a bash script, a list of ip addresses is being sorted  by  the number of occurrences:

```
  | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

​now you have 2 columns, e.g.

```
120 188.12.91.63
 85 112.12.91.76
 83 104.100.42.98
 36 200.187.165.142
 30 200.187.165.161
```

Question:  I want to get a 3 column output. e.g. the third column to be some function of the second column (e.g. the function can be some filtered output of nslookup). HOW do I add a third column? Can it be done in the pipe or should I export the above two columns to a variable? Then how?  I am a newbie, thank you!

Comment: You'd pipe the sort -rn output into a shell while-read loop, or into awk or some other program that lets you implement the ip function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```sh
echo "120 188.12.91.63
 85 112.12.91.76
 83 104.100.42.98
 36 200.187.165.142
 30 200.187.165.161" |  while IFS=" " read -r count ip; do
   name=$(nslookup "$ip" | awk -v ip="$ip" '/name/{print substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1)}')
   echo $count $ip $name
done
```

You might want to replace the initial echo with the command that you've used to obtain the list of IP Addresses.

Comment: That works, great!  Thank you very much!  
I only introduced " ="  without the quotes, after /name so that it returns the name of the node only. Otherwise in some cases, not always, it may return the names of the dns servers as well.